# My Update table function doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I have been creating a cookbook with added features , I cant seem to get the updating the recipe feature to work through tkinter

I have attempted multiple types of code but i just cant seem to get it , here is my code for just altering the table , but it doesnt seem to alter the table and instead just swaps back, I have managed to condense it down into this:

```
            #not used yet
            def Change_and_exit(id):
                Alter_Recipe(id)
                for element in window.winfo_children():
                    element.destroy()
                Recipe_page()


            def Alter_Recipe(id):
                NewRecName = New_Name_input.get()
                NewRecRegion = New_Region_input.get()
                NewIngredients = New_Ingredients_input.get()
                NewRecMethod = New_Method_input.get()
                Recipe_id = id
                mycursor.execute("UPDATE Recipe SET name = %s ,region = %s ,ingredients = %s ,method = %s WHERE RecipeID = %s", (NewRecName,NewRecRegion,NewIngredients,NewRecMethod,Recipe_id))
                db.commit()

                

            def New_temp_text_Name(e):
                New_Name_input.delete(0,"end")
            def New_temp_text_Region(e):
                New_Region_input.delete(0,"end")
            def New_temp_text_Ingredients(e):
                New_Ingredients_input.delete(0,"end")
            def New_temp_text_Method(e):
                New_Method_input.delete(0,"end")
            Hide_buttons()

            NameText = row[0]
            RegionText = row[1]
            IngredientsText = row[2]
            MethodText = row[3]

            
            New_Name_input = ttk.Entry(window)
            New_Name_input.insert(0, "" + NameText + "")
            New_Name_input.place(x=630,y=150,width=300, height = 50)
            New_Name_input.bind("<FocusIn>", New_temp_text_Name)
            New_Region_input = ttk.Entry(window)
            New_Region_input.insert(0, "" + RegionText + "")
            New_Region_input.place(x=630,y=250,width=300, height = 50)
            New_Region_input.bind("<FocusIn>", New_temp_text_Region)
            New_Ingredients_input = ttk.Entry(window)
            New_Ingredients_input.insert(0, "" + IngredientsText + "")
            New_Ingredients_input.place(x=630,y=350,width=300, height = 60)
            New_Ingredients_input.bind("<FocusIn>", New_temp_text_Ingredients)
            New_Method_input = ttk.Entry(window)
            New_Method_input.insert(0,"" + MethodText + "")
            New_Method_input.place(x=630,y=450,width=300, height = 100)
            New_Method_input.bind("<FocusIn>", New_temp_text_Method)
            Change_and_exit_button = ttk.Button(window,text = "Change and Exit",command=Change_and_exit(row[4]))
            Change_and_exit_button.place(x=1030,y=550,width=100, height = 50)

    
        mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Recipe')   
        for row in mycursor.fetchall():
            recipeselect = ttk.Button(window, text = row[0])
            recipeselect.config(command= lambda row=row:text_page(row))
            recipeselect.pack()
```

if there is any advice or help to fix this please let me know

Comment: The UPDATE SQL statement seems OK.  Did you check the value of `id` passed to `Alter_Recipe()`?  Does the table contain record with the same value in `RecipeID` column?

Comment: Note that `command=Change_and_exit(row[4])` will execute `Change_and_exit()` immediately and assign the result (which is `None`) to the `command` option.  So nothing will be done when the button is clicked later.

Comment: Change `command=Change_and_exit(row[4])` to `command=lambda: Change_and_exit(row[4])`.